# Android Development in VS 2010 using C#

Tags: c#, android

I would like to use C# for developing mobile apps for the Android Framework. I have looked at MonoDroid, just downloaded, yet to install. I would like to be able to deploy to a device rather than just the emulator. Are there any other options out there of we are stuck with MonoDroid and the $399 that comes with the Licence?

Comment: As I understand their licensing, you can deploy to an emulator all day long for free. You don't need to pay for a license until you want to deploy to a device. 399 USD sounds like a reasonable fee if you're developing software to sell.

Comment: I think your right. Only issue is that how can you show a client what you have if you have to actually go over with your laptop and launch the IDE+Emulator. Tho the $ seems fair for the headache it saves (from blog posts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nomad](http://vsnomad.com/) looks interesting. Haven't tried it yet, but appears that it builds HTML5 apps (as opposed to native apps)? It can build for both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to develop, if this is a game you might want to check **Unity**, it's a free Game Engine. They support .NET Based Scripting with C# and JavaScript. For Android and iOS you should purchase an add on, but they had offered a 30 day trial before, better check this out by your self.
https://store.unity3d.com/products